Flavour based dependency in Android causing duplication issues
I have 3 flavours in my application uat, staging, production and I have dependency of external library that has 3 flavours uat, staging and production.
I'm fetching this individual dependencies in my android application using:
uatImplementation("com.external-dependency.xyz:0.1.0:uat-release@aar")
stagingImplementation("com.external-dependency.xyz:0.1.0:staging-release@aar")
productionImplementation("com.external-dependency.xyz:0.1.0:production-release@aar")

This has caused issues
Execution failed for task ':app:checkStagingDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
 Duplicate class hilt_aggregated_deps._TestFunctionality_AndroidModule found in modules.

